# Change name of variable like in ng-repeat but without repeating?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my app I have, say `$scope.item`. In my page I have templates that refer to that as something else, say `$scope.product`.

On one page I need to refer to the model as `item`, but then use `ng-include` to open templates that refer to it as `product`.

When I had just one item in an array, I did `ng-repeat="product in item"`. Now I done away with the single array with an object and it's just an object. If I do `ng-repeat` it will repeat for each key/value pair in the object. Not what I want.

Is there a way to say `ng-alias="item as product"` or something?

Comment: I am commenting because I am just conjecturing, but if you have a controller you could do something like this.product = $scope.item ...

Comment: Yepp, `{{ this.item = product }}` worked perfectly.

Comment: Oops, actually if you do that it will also print out the object in plain text on the page.

Comment: You can do it in ng-init, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a one-time binding you could do

```
<... ng-init="product = item" ...>
```

However from what I understand you where hacking ng-repeat for aliasing purpose with no real need to repeat. In this case `ng-init` will still be a hack that can cause you trouble later on.

The proper way to do what you want is put your template into a directive, and link the `product` variable of your directive from the given item. i.e. the html would look like this:

```
<my-directive product="item"></my-directive>
```

Answer (score 1):

ngInit was intended for aliasing.

```
ng-init="item = product"
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.